# MongoDB count different values in multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, count, aggregation

I want to count how often a unique value occurs. I have multiple arrays with objects like:

> {“value”:”a”,”begin”:0,”end”:12}

but I only need the “value” part of the object so I projected only the values so the result of my projection looks like this but with multiple arrays:

> {“values”:[{“value”:”a”},{“value”:”b”},{“value”:”b”}]}

My goal is to get a result array with all different values and how often they occurred in all multiple arrays:

> [{“value”:”a”,”count”:1},{“value”:”b”,”count”:2}]

Comment: You can use `$unwind` and `$group` with `{$sum:1}`

Comment: i dont know where my error is but i cant unwind the arrays. Would it be {$unwind: {path: "values"}?

Comment: You can use `{$unwind: "$values"}`. Please provide few sample documents and I'll show you

Comment: For example i would get 2 Documents with following data.
`{
 "values": [
  "value": "a",
  "value": "b",
  "value": "c",
  "value": "a",
  "value": "b",
  "value": "c"
 ]
}`

`{
 "values": [
  "value": "a",
  "value": "b",
  "value": "d",
  "value": "g",
  "value": "d",
  "value": "c"
 ]
}`
And as result i need:
`{
 {"value": "a", "count": 3},
 {"value": "b", "count": 3},
 {"value": "c", "count": 3},
 {"value": "d", "count": 2},
 {"value": "g", "count": 1},
 
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$values"},
  {$group: {_id: "$values.value", count: {$sum: 1}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7VNVBWoHXDL)